# Asociar Checkbox y Spinner

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola estimados buenas noches, espero me puedan ayudar con esto.

Estoy implementando un sistema que me permita asignar uniformes a cada trabajador.
Actualmente así es mi interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán por cada área muestro que uniformes usan, cada checkbox al seleccionarlo es como si se le va a entregar 1 UNIDAD de ese uniforme, pero quiero ver la forma de colocarle al costado un SPINNER, para que se puedan elegir la cantidad a entregar y ya no sea solo 1 UND.

En mi archivo cargar_uniformes.php le he agregado un spinner a cada uno quedando de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código cargar_uniformes.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php  
$id = $_GET['id'];//recibo el ID del área seleccionada     
include("../includes/conexion.php");                    
    
//$query = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes WHERE area_id =".$id );     
$query = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes WHERE area_id = '.$id.'   AND  stock > 0");                
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$html="";
//print json_encode($data);
foreach ($data as $value)
$html.='<li> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'" id="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'"> <label for="'.$value["id_uniforme"].'">'.$value["descripcion"].'</label> <input type="number" name="spinner[]" value="1"></li>';

echo $html;   //imprimo cada uniforme del area en forma de CHECKBOX y lo devuelvo ?>
```

Actualmente para guardar los datos en mi BD y restarle 1 UND  al stock por cada uniforme retirado usaba un "foreach" este es mi codigo:

```
foreach ($checkbox as $seleccion) // PARA CADA CHECKBOX 'UNIFORME ' SELECCIONADO
{

    $query = ("SELECT * FROM tabla_uniformes WHERE id_uniforme=" .$seleccion);
    $consulta=$bd->query($query);
                                        
        while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $stock= $fila['stock'];  // LLAMO EL STOCK ACTUAL DE UNIFORME SELECCIONADO
            $descripcion= $fila['descripcion']; // LLAMO TAMBIEN EL NOMBRE DEL UNIFORME
            $newstock = $stock - 1 ;  //RESTO AL STOCK 1 UNIDAD
            //print($resultado);

                if ( $newstock >= 0)  //VERIFICAMOS SI AL RESTARLE 1 AUN QUEDA O NO STOCK, SI ES NEGATIVO EL STOCK ESTA EN '0'
                {
                  /*------------------------------------------------------------                        
                    $sentencia = $bd->prepare("UPDATE tabla_uniformes SET stock = ? WHERE id_uniforme = ?;");
                    $resultado1 = $sentencia->execute([$newstock,$seleccion]);  //ACTUALIZAMOS EL NUEVO STOCK EN LA TABLA UNIFORMES
                                                
                    if ($resultado1 === TRUE) { // SI TODO FUE CORRECTO AGREGO LOS DATOS DE LA PERSONA A LA TABLA ENTREGAS
                                                            
                        $sentencia = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla_entregas(dni,descripcion,fecha) VALUES (?,?,?);");
                        $resultado2 = $sentencia->execute([$dni,$descripcion,$fecha]);} // AGREGAMOS A LA TABLA DE ENTREGAS 
                                                
                    if ($resultado2 === TRUE) {

                         echo "<script>  
                            alert('CORRECTO');
                            window.location= '../vistas/m-entregar.php'
                            </script>";
                    
                    //header("location:../vistas/m-entregar.php"); // SI TODO FUE CORRECTO REGRESAMOS A LA PESTAÑA DE ENTREGAR
                                    
                    }else{
                        echo "Error";   } // ERROR

                    

                /*------------------------------------------------------------
                }else{
                
                    

                      echo "<script>  
                            alert('No hay stock suficiente');
                            window.location= '../vistas/m-entregar.php'
                            </script>";
                    

                }
                        
        }

}
```

Entonces a lo que voy es como podría hacer para que cada vez que seleccione uno o mas uniformes (chekboxes), lo que va a restar es el valor que tiene el SPINNER al costado, como pueden ver el "name"
del cada SPINNER esta con corchetes [] para poder recibir el array pero siempre obtengo el valor de TODOS LOS SPINNER y no solo del uniforme(checkbox) que esta seleccionado.

Espero me entiendan y  puedan ayudar, si necesitan mas info me avisan. gracias!!!
pdt, si tienen alguna propuesta de como mejorar esto bienvenida sea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el id del uniforme como índice, y así identificas fácilmente a que uniforme corresponde cada spinner

```
<?php
// resto del codigo

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $idUniforme = $value["id_uniforme"];
    $html.='<li> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$idUniforme.'" id="'.$idUniforme.'"> <label for="'.$idUniforme.'">'.$value["descripcion"].'</label> <input type="number" name="spinner['.$idUniforme.']" value="1"></li>';
}
```

Luego

```
$spinners = $_POST['spinner'];

foreach ($checkbox as $seleccion) {
// ...
    while ($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // ... 
        $newstock = $stock - $spinners[$seleccion];
```